# appending inner SVG elements to a DOM element with SnapSVG

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, snap.svg

I'm able to load a few SVGs and append them (the nodes) to a DOM element using:

`container.appendChild( fragment.node.cloneNode(true) );`

Now if I want to do the same, but by loading only one SVG file and extracting nodes from it, like:

`let myElement = fragment.select( '#elementID' );`
`container.appendChild( myElement.node.cloneNode(true) );`

...that doesn't work, and I assume it's because `myElement` is an element and not a fragment. `myElement.node` shows a  tag that isn't wrapped by an SVG element.

How do I wrap an SVG element around `myElement` so I can append it to another DOM element?

Comment: Yes - a `<circle>` (or any other shape) without a containing `<svg>` has no context. No `viewBox` coordinate system. Nothing with which it can render.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that makes sense..do you know a solution for that? I tried using `Snap( myElement )` but that does change anything... maybe it's just me, but I can't find any clue on the documentation

Comment: It's possible you can do snapContainer.append( loadedFragment.select('#someid').clone() ) but really as mentioned elsewhere, you need to include a minimal testing example to see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding on the assumption that your "source" SVG is contained in the document, and that's how you're selecting it, you don't actually need anything special.

```
<svg viewBox="[appropriate values here]">
    <use xlink:href="#elementID" />
</svg>
```

This will "clone" the element with the given ID without any further effort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my source SVG is not contained in the document, it's loaded at some point in the app... but the elements I'm "selecting" with Snap are `<g>`, not `<use>` - is that a problem? I'm not sure what you mean. It seems I'm following the wrong approach to do the whole thing but I can't think of any other.

Comment: The element you are selecting can be anything. `<use>` is just the lookup to it. If you're loading it in at some point, you can always dump the whole thing to DOM for free, and just give it `display:none`. `<use>` will of course still work.

Comment: I see. I'm struggling to understand why I need to dump the whole thing to DOM, but I'll give it a try. Cheers

Comment: Putting the whole thing to DOM allows `xlink:href` to find the element in question.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Should I use document.createElement() and pass an SVG with an <use> tag like the one in your example and append to the DOM? That doesn't seem to work. Sorry but I think I've got it all wrong in my head, what I want to do is [really really simple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48623153/795398)